# making responsive drop down in responsive container

Tags: html, css

I am practicing css. I am trying out following.

1st thing:

Having a div with two dropdowns:
[image: div with dropdown]

My code is as follows:

html:

```
<div class="rectangle">
   <div class="selection">
      Selection
   </div>
   <div>
        <div>Dropdown1</div>
        <div>dropdown</div>
        <div>Dropdown2</div>
        <div>dropdown</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle {
  width:90%;
  border-raidus:2vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:auto;
}

.selection {
  padding: 0.5rem 0rem 0rem 3rem;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem
}
```

How can I make responsive div with two dropdowns? I want to make it responsive so that they are at same place and same look and feel at all screen sizes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with setting "display: flex" on your parent container.

```
.rectangle {
  display: flex;
}
```

Checkout this Guide for flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here is a example for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-css-assignment-qzwivu?file=style.scss

Comment: in this I have two problems, one is dropdown should start in same alignment as selection . and dropdown should not go to another line,